# Powershell Pattern Matching Regular Expression

Tags: regex, powershell, match

On our servers we  have files similar to the following:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_01\
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_02\
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Sun\Java\jre1.6.0_03\
etc
```

We don't need these files any more so I am trying to write a powershell script to delete them. For now I am limiting myself to one particular server and I have the following script:

```
 $path = "\\server\c$\Documents and Settings\"
 Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_ -match '^jre1.6.0_')} | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

The problem is that the pattern I am using doesn't seem to be calling a match and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried several permutations and none seem to work. Can any regex gurus out there shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks
Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Force | ....
```

`-Force` looks for hidden or system files/folders also.

The "Application Data" folder is Hidden!

Comment: That was it! It wasn't going into the hidden folders. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The regex is ok, I think you should try

```
$_.Name -match '^jre1.6.0_'
```

and not just

```
$_ -match '^jre1.6.0_'
```

Comment: Using `$_ -match ...` relies on the object's `ToString()` behavior.  So yeah, I'd use `$_.Name -match ...` in a script.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working either. I've let the script run for 10+ minutes and its not returning anything. I'll continue to let it run till it completes to see if maybe it just needs more time to recurse all the directories.

Comment: It finally finished - no results. PS C:\Documents and Settings\user\desktop> .\cleanjava.ps1
PS C:\Documents and Settings\user\desktop>

Comment: @Brad: maybe you got no results because you are filtering on `$_.PSIsContainer`, and that gets only directories?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am looking for - directories whose name begins with jre1.6.0_

Comment: I want to delete the directory and anything inside it.

Comment: @Brad: sorry, misread the question. If you remove the -match and just list the containers, do you get the folders you are looking for? If not, the problem might be somewhere else (e.g. permissions).

Comment: If I remove the -match its going to match every folder under c$\Documents and Settings\ which i don't want to remove. I only specifically want to delete folders (and contents) that match jre1.6.0_01, jre1.6.0_02, jre1.6.0_03 etc.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10988/discussion-between-paolo-tedesco-and-brad)

Comment: @Brad: you say that it's going to list all the folder, but have you tried it (without the Remove-Item at the end, of course)?
Does the output of `Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse | Where {$_.PSIsContainer} | % {$_.FullName}` include those folders? If not, the problem is not the regexp.